# ORDER Direction (ASC/DESC) can't be used as a parameter in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing some parameterised queries, and I noticed that using a parameter for the "ASC/DESC" part of the ORDER isn't allowed in SQL Server 2008.  This gives the error `Incorrect syntax near '@p'.`:

```
declare @p nvarchar
set @p = 'desc'

select * from Customer order by CustomerID @p
```

However using a parameter for the number of results works fine, provided you use brackets around it.

```
declare @p int
set @p = 5

select top (@p) * from Customer order by CustomerID
```

Is there any reason for this, and any workarounds?

This question suggests one workaround, but doesn't say why it's needed:
[DESC and ASC as a parameter in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019758/desc-and-asc-as-a-parameter-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: The main difference I see is that `5`is a regular value while `desc` is part of the SQL language. This would turn your query into dynamic or force you to use `case` statements.

Comment: @MorganBardon posted this link as an answer if it's useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207954/using-variables-for-asc-and-desc-in-order-by

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you crossed the 15 points border yourself you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @tbl(SomeValue) VALUES('a'),('b'),('c');

DECLARE @sortDirection VARCHAR(10)='ASC';

SELECT *
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sortDirection='DESC' THEN ID END DESC
        ,CASE WHEN @sortDirection='ASC' THEN ID END ASC
```

#### EDIT

I took away the `ELSE 0`. It's not needed and would make troubles if the sort column is not `INT`

Comment: just to add to the answer, SQL will still sort on both the columns. adding a case helps that when sortDirection is 'ASC', the evaluated `ORDER BY` becomes `ORDER BY 0 DESC, Id ASC` which is really `ORDER BY Id ASC`

Comment: @strugo, yes, you're right...  you have to do something to expression to reverse its sort order...  using -id (minus id) works though

Comment: `order by case @sortDirection when 'Desc' then id else -id end`

Comment: @CharlesBretana - Nice idea for numerical columns.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, Nice trick! Tiny hint: You mixed the directions... One draw back: This would not work with non-numeric columns...

Comment: @Shnugo,  right.  I deleted my original (incorrect) comment.

Comment: hah!  your moniker is not easy to read and re-spell correctly!

Comment: and it would work with dates, and with character data that is not too long.... `order by case @sortDirection when 'desc' then -Cast(Cast(varcharColumn as varbinary) as bigint) else Cast(Cast(varcharColumn as varbinary) as bigint) end`  as long as varcharColumn is small enough

Comment: @CharlesBretana, With conversions... You'd probably get into *sargability* issues...#

Comment: but with order by you need to read all records in set anyway... so sargability is not issue?

Comment: @CharlesBretana, converting to `VARBINARY` might be dangerous (unexpected negativ)? Would have to think about this a bit more...

Comment: @CharlesBretana Oh yes, it is... The usage of indexes is absolutely crucial with sorting, isn't it?

Comment: but sargability has to do with reducing the number of IOs necessary to perform a task, by reading nodes in b-tree to filter records instead of performing a table scan and examining every record.  If you have to read every record anyway,  processor could use index, but table scan is fewer IOs cause there's only one IO per record, whereas in index there's n IOs per record (where n is number of levels in b-Tree)

Comment: Actually, one IO per page in disk image of table. (and we're about to get yelled at for using comments to have conversation...)

Comment: @CharlesBretana, you might [read this](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/01/19/sargable-expression-performance/). But I think this discussion is off topic actually, as the `CASE` itself makes it unSARGable already...

Comment: http://josef-richberg.squarespace.com/journal/2010/1/28/is-a-case-statement-considered-sargable.html   or http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2010/02/02/a-case-study-in-sargability.aspx

Comment: "The thing that is SARGable is the term that is indexed",  i.e., the column in the table, not the entire case expression

Comment: @CharlesBretana, Good night :-) I'm living in Vienna/Austria/Europe... Started to work just 2 hours ago :-) Good night to you!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a stored procedure:

```
    DECLARE @sqlQuery AS NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @Order AS NVARCHAR(255) = 'DESC'

    SET @sqlQuery = '
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.DimCustomer
        ORDER BY CustomerKey ' +  @Order


    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic SQL. You can prepare a query by code like tihs

```
declare @top int = 5;
declare @order varchar(4) = 'desc';

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'select top (' + cast(@top as varchar(max)) + ') * from Customer order by CustomerID ' + @order;
```

If you try the `select @sql;` then you will see that the `@sql` is

> select top (5) * from Customer order by CustomerID desc

Now you can execute your query by `sp_executesql` function like in this way

```
execute sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DQ.* FROM (
                 SELECT *,
                       (row_number() 
                           OVER (ORDER BY employeeID)) * 
                              CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'ASC' THEN 
                                   1 
                              ELSE 
                                   -1 
                              END sort 
                                   from employeemaster) DQ
                   ORDER BY DQ.sort
```

you could then reverse any sort, including sorts on multiple fields ans sort on nun-numeric

Comment: The simple `CASE` solution of my answer allows an execution plan using indexes (read about *sargable* or follow the discussion below my answer),   yours could get quite slow with big data. And one more point: If you want to sort one column `ASC` and another `DESC` you would get in troubles...

Comment: And btw: Charles suggestion (in comment below my answer) does exactly the same without the unneeded complexity. And - as there - you would get into troubles if the column is not numeric...